# How to load a simplexmlobject file into a variable

Tags: php

I am going crazy here...

I already have a SimpleXMLElement Object so it is not an XML file...
I got it stored in a file object.txt

Now i want to put this object into a variable, but i can't get it to work...?

the SimpleXMLElement Object looks like this:

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PubmedArticle] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [MedlineCitation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Owner] => NLM
                                    [Status] => In-Process
                                )

```
                        [PMID] => 20538400
                        [DateCreated] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Year] => 2010
                                [Month] => 07
                                [Day] => 08
                            )

                        [Article] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [PubModel] => Print-Electronic
                                    )
```

.....etc etc....

how do i put this into a variable??

i tried this:
$simplexml = file_get_contents('object.xml');

$simplexml should be an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading simplexml from file: [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php): `$a = simplexml_load_file('object.xml');`
If you need something else, please explain.

Comment: It doesn't work... when i use the load simplexml_load_file it is expecting a "<" starting tag... but actually it is an array that i'm trying to load...

Comment: Array in which form? Serialized? Printed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If your 'object.xml' file contains the above example and not actual XML, it looks a lot like you are using the results of a vardump, and you possibly wish to load that into a (or several) SimpleXMLElementObject(s)...

So, really, you have a string inside of a text file, and you want to parse out the contents. I found this: [converting text file into xml using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445825/converting-text-file-into-xml-using-php) and thought it would be a good starting point.